# Socket.Io with Vue and Node Js +Express. App needs to be manually reloaded to trigger sockets connections

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, socket.io

Good day developers. I´ve been working my first time ever with socket.Io,and I´m trying to understand its all processes. For this i have decide to use Vue as client-side and NodeJs+Express being the server.

In a nutshell for client side(Vue) the app might have some security to login ...and in there once the user is logged in would be redirected to the app view, where is expected the socket connects(or at least is expected the server sends the connect signal):

I also have set a socket service in front side in order to connect to server url using io, and this sevice is initialised on every  component:

```
import io, { Socket } from "socket.io-client";
const ioUrl = `http://${process.env.VUE_APP_IO_BACK_URL}`;
export const getSocketConnector = (): Socket<any, any> => {
  
  return io(ioUrl, {
    extraHeaders: {
      "token-response": localStorage.getItem("token") as string,
    },
    multiplex: false,
    reconnection: true,
    transports: ["websocket"],
  });
};
```

then in my login component:

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { getSocketConnector } from "@/services/socket-services/socket-service";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "login-component",
  data() {
    return {
      socket: getSocketConnector(),
      password: "" as string,
      nickname: "" as string,
      email: "" as string,
      mail,
      
    };
  },

  setup() {
    return {};
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["loginUserAction"]),

    loginUser(): void {
     
        this.loginUserAction({
          nickname: this.nickname,
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
      
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.socket;
  },
});
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

and my store(im using vuex), where all the actions related to login and others are triggered ...look like this:

```
import { AxiosDataToken } from "@/interfaces/response-interfaces";
import router from "@/router";
import { AuthServices } from "@/services/auth-services/auth-services";
import { getSocketConnector } from "@/services/socket-services/socket-service";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { createStore } from "vuex";

const authServices = new AuthServices();
const serverURL = `http://${process.env.VUE_APP_IO_BACK_URL}`;
const socket = getSocketConnector();
const store = createStore({
  state: {
    loginSkeletonLoader: false as boolean,
    signupSkeletonLoader: false as boolean,
    user: {} as User,
   
    allUsers: [] as User[],
    
  } as AppState,

  getters: {

    //================================================================
    getter_user_signed(state:AppState): User {
      return state.user;
    },
    getter_all(state:AppState): AppState {
      return state;
    },
    
    //================================================================
    getter_all_users(state:AppState): User[] {
      return state.allUsers;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
   
    //============================================================
    commit_all_users(state: AppState, payload: User[]): void {
      state.allUsers = payload;
    },

    

    
    //===================================================
    commit_set_user_data(state: AppState, payload: User): void {
      state.user = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    

    //==================================================================
    getAllUsers({ commit, dispatch }, payload: any): void {
      axios
        .get(`${serverURL}/user/get/all/users`)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse<AxiosDataToken>) => {
          commit("commit_all_users", response.data.allUsers);
        })
        .then(async () => {
          router.push(`/tabs/tab-all-users`);
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => {
          error;
        });
    },
    //====================================================================
    loginUserAction(
      { commit, dispatch },
      userLoggingPayload: UserLoginData
    ): void {
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8100",
      };
      commit("commit_set_skeleton_login", true);

      axios
        .post(`${serverURL}/auth/login/user`, userLoggingPayload, { headers })
        .then((response: AxiosResponse<AxiosDataToken>) => {
          authServices.tokenStorer(response.data?.token);
          socket.emit("FLAG-ALL-USERS", response.data);

          commit("commit_set_user_data", response.data.user);
          dispatch("getAllUsers");
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => {
          error;
        })
        .finally(() => commit("commit_set_skeleton_login", false));
    },

   //======================================================================
    socketListenerAction({ commit, dispatch }): void {
      
      socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connectadoa si");
        dispatch("getAllUsers");
      });

      
      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        const payload = false;
        dispatch("getAllUsers");
      });
.....other event listeners....
    },
  },
  modules: {},
});

export default store;
```

as you could se the login action would dispatch another one(getAllUsers)if login credentials  passes, and is there when i expect the socket connects, or at least the back end sends that connection, but is not happening unless i reload the page.
Also this store has another method called `socketListenerAction`  the one in charge of listening all events sent from back.

In the back end, putting aside al config, there are 2 specific point i would like to expose.
The socket-controller,and  the controller that gives access to the app view :
App View Controller:

```
  const getAllUsers = async (req = request, res = response) => {
  const { pagination = 3, startingIn = 0 } = req.query;
  const userActiveOnly = { userState: true };
  const [allUsers, total] = await Promise.all([
    User.find(userActiveOnly)
      .skip(Number(startingIn))
      .limit(Number(pagination)),
   
    User.countDocuments(userActiveOnly),
  ]);

  if (allUsers) {
    return res.status(201).json({
      allUsers,
      total,
    });
  }
};
module.exports = {
  getAllUsers
}
```

and the route called with  this controller once the login is a success would be like this:

ROUTES:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const {
  getAllUsers,
} = require("../controllers/user-controller");
const router = Router();
router.get("/get/all/users", getAllUsers);
module.exports = router;
```

The socket controller for server would be like this:
SOCKET CONTROLLER

```
const { Socket } = require("socket.io");

const socketController = async (socket = new Socket(), io) => {
try {
    const handshakeHeader = await socket.handshake.headers["token-response"];
if (!user || user == undefined) {
      return socket.disconnect();
    }

 io.emit("ACTIVE-USERS", some payload);
 socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      ;
      io.emit("ACTIVE-USERS", some payload);
    });

...other sockets listeners and emitters.....
} catch (error) {
    socket.disconnect();
    
  }}
```

and this socket controller would be called in the server config:
SERVER:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors")
const corsObject = {
  origin: [
    
    "http://xxx.xxx.xx:8100",
    "http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8100",
  ],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"],
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Content-Type",
    "Authorization",
    "token-response",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  ],
  exposedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"],
  credentials: true,
  withCredentials: true,
};

const { conectToMongo } = require("../database/database");
const {
  socketController,
} = require("../sockets-controllers/socket-controller");


class Server {
  allowedOrigins: string[];
  app: any;
  port: any;
  server: any;
  io: any;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express(); 
    this.port = process.env.PORT; 

    this.connectingdatabase();
 this.server = require("http").createServer(this.app);
this.io = require("socket.io")(this.server, {
      cors: corsObject,
    });
this.connectionSocketClient()
this.middlewares()
this.routes(); 
  }

 middlewares() {
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.static("public")); 
    this.app.use(cors()); //cors
    this.app.get("/", (request, response, next) => {
      response.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        message: "request correct",
      });
    });
    this.app.use(
      fileUpload({
        useTempFiles: true,
        tempFileDir: "/tmp/",
        createParentPath: true,
      })
    );
  }

routes() {
    this.app.use("/user", require("../routes/user-routes"));
    this.app.use("/auth", require("../routes/user-login"));
   ...more routes....
  }

async connectingdatabase() {
    await conectToMongo();
  }

 connectionSocketClient() {
    this.io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socketController(socket, this.io);
    });
  }

portListener() {
    this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
      console.log(`server running on port : ${this.port}`);
    });
 }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

This would be the main picture, despite i omit some methods or folders or parts of code not related with the problem.
And as i told in the begining the main problem is , once i login and the router pushes to the main app view , the socket in client side is not able to listen the evnt connect from server side(or server side does not emit it), thus in order to trigger that is neccesary to reload the page.
Would be great any help about this.
Thanks in advance